# .on('click')/off('click') - on not refiring

Tags: jquery, onclick, carousel

This is a semi-carousel that pulls dynamic content from a database so the amount of elements in the carousel changes. The initial right click button is disabled to prevent user from displaying the blank area to the left of the first one. When the scroller gets to the last element, the left click button is disabled to prevent displaying a blank area to the right of last element. I created a range to enable/disable the click elements. Going back and forth once works - after that the buttons are disabled but the disabled class was removed so it didn't re-bind.

Any assistance/guidance greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.rght-arrw').off('click').addClass('disabled');

         $('.left-arrw').click(function () {
            $('.nav-content').animate({ left: '-=151' });
            var newCarouselX = $('.nav-content').position();
            var boxWidth = $('.nav-content').width();
            var navWidth = $('.nav-frame').width();
            var scrollMove = ((boxWidth - navWidth)*(-1)) + 165;
             if (newCarouselX.left < 50 && newCarouselX.left > scrollMove) {
                $('.rght-arrw').on('click').removeClass('disabled');
                } 
             else {
                $('.left-arrw').off('click').addClass('disabled');
            } 
             event.preventDefault(); 
        });

         $('.rght-arrw').click(function () {
             $('.left-arrw').on('click').removeClass('disabled');
             $('.nav-content').animate({ left: '+=150' });
             var newCarouselX = $('.nav-content').position();
             var boxWidth = $('.nav-content').width();
             var navWidth = $('.nav-frame').width();
             var scrollMove = ((boxWidth - navWidth)*(-1)) ;
             if (newCarouselX.left < -50 && newCarouselX.left < scrollMove) {
                $('.left-arrw').on('click').removeClass('disabled');
            } 
             else {
                $('.rght-arrw').off('click').addClass('disabled');
            } 
            event.preventDefault();
         });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled the click in this code:

```
$('.rght-arrw').off('click').addClass('disabled');
```

and then you added that code:

```
 $('.rght-arrw').click(function () {
```

That is why the click does not work.

Comment: it works back and forth twice and then stops. Trying to figure out how to get the click events to work until the boundaries are reached and then disable as necessary

Comment: I would advise no to use element left attribute but the images count and current index.